# Base64 encoding producing extremily long results

Tags: vb.net, base64

Creating a simple base64 encoding as an example. Problem is when storing the results (the encoded string) in an access DB the returned string is greater than the DB field will allow? max field length is 255. Why is the result for an average string of 8-15 characters resulting in 350+ character encoded result. example salt is `"abcdefgh"`

```
Public Function EncodePassword(ByVal pass As String, ByVal passwordFormat As Integer, ByVal salt As String) As String
    If passwordFormat = 0 Then Return pass
    Dim bIn As Byte() = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pass)
    Dim bSalt As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(salt)
    Dim bAll As Byte() = New Byte(bSalt.Length + bIn.Length - 1) {}
    Dim bRet As Byte() = Nothing
    Buffer.BlockCopy(bSalt, 0, bAll, 0, bSalt.Length)
    Buffer.BlockCopy(bIn, 0, bAll, bSalt.Length, bIn.Length)

    If passwordFormat = 1 Then
        Dim s As HashAlgorithm = HashAlgorithm.Create(_HashAlgorithmType)

        If s Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ProviderException("Could not create a hash algorithm")
        End If

        bRet = s.ComputeHash(bAll)
    Else
        bRet = EncryptPassword(bAll)
    End If

    Return Convert.ToBase64String(bRet)
End Function
```

Comment: Why do you want to base64 encode a hash? Also which hash algorithm are you using? This doesn't really have anything to do with base64 encoding but rather with the hash size?

Comment: `passwordFormat = 3` hash is not part of the question... sorry for confusion.

Comment: Can you provide a sample string with a length between 8 and 15 characters, that when encoded to Base64 exceeds 255 characters?

Comment: sample pass is BCCRSPp2019 expected result: results = `QnjWXez3+Fcb9dgSygTuRTnYbxgLVhywsAVWZRQt6Ro=` actual result: `QnjWXez3+Fcb9dgSygTuRWG79wtdD7hkZqy60P1m9dh9RK1upgG5T3wqPhSj1tIyefIyJh0dXo2alARQ93lMJk0sDQ+qSxHRQLGGr2jBqmxCq5Bph1+d72gf7fQTyzJvKXeGChciIwcvoIzWMJNwjNN8OK9pCL+h5lTlUCeDQs5xhwZSMiDsP9CIyDpaDnGhkRq0ugqE1ogXYQHwdM1G3wNJTHUEut3g5ZnQB6sxrZ7YEfMR5meweAOokw65Q59vzI0U40h1wNaTOkoqR1InxC6dkXa9xK5EEriczyhSw/ArJ6JWSKg/h+jzbYCO92lmNbplp1X4uiRfvSeqmJLdWnogoYNQCunISGfefR6xNXc=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the string `pass` returned from the DB had trailing spaces to fill the length of the 128 chr DB field (a 20 character password had 108 spaces trailing the end).

Fixed with `pass.TrimEnd()`